# Create personalized validator for form by easyadmin with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

## The problem

Hi everybody ! I'm new on stackoverflow and in symfony. Before I came here, i've tried some solutions like create validator or insert functions directly in my entity or repository and call them into my CrudController but I still block...

I've 7 entities : User, Hideout, Agent, Contact, Mission, Speciality and Target (it's for a dummy project for training myself) and I use easyadmin to have CRUD on all of them.

Everything works well but in my MissionCrudController, I need to specify error if contact's nationality is different of the mission's country for example. And I don't know how I can do that without make a form by myself. I even don't know how to use Validators to help me.

Or maybe the solution is to create filters ? When user enters the mission's country, contacts from this country will be display ?

Maybe someone can explain it to me ?

Thanks in advance !
(And sorry for my english !)

## And this is my code :

### MissionCrudController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Mission;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ChoiceField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CountryField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextareaField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class MissionCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Mission::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('title'),
            TextareaField::new('description')->hideOnIndex(),
            ChoiceField::new('type')->setChoices([
                'Murder' => 'Murder',
                'Surveillance' => 'Surveillance',
                'Infiltration' => 'Infiltration',
                'Kidnapping' => 'Kidnapping',
                'Extraction' => 'Extraction',
            ]),
            CountryField::new('country'),
            DateField::new('startDate')->hideOnIndex(),
            DateField::new('endDate')->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('speciality')->hideOnIndex(),
            AssociationField::new('agent')->setRequired(true),
            AssociationField::new('target')->setRequired(true),
            AssociationField::new('contact')->setRequired(true),
            AssociationField::new('hideout'),
            ChoiceField::new('status')->setChoices([
                'Preparation' => 'Preparation',
                'Started' => 'Started',
                'Finished' => 'Finished',
                'Failed' => 'Failed',
            ]),
        ];
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
    return $crud
        ->setPageTitle('index', 'Missions');
    }
}
```

### Contact.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ContactRepository::class)]
class Contact
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column()]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $lastname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $codeName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $nationality = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, mappedBy: 'contact')]
    private Collection $missions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->missions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateOfBirth(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateOfBirth;
    }

    public function setDateOfBirth(\DateTimeInterface $dateOfBirth): self
    {
        $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeName;
    }

    public function setCodeName(string $codeName): self
    {
        $this->codeName = $codeName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNationality(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nationality;
    }

    public function setNationality(string $nationality): self
    {
        $this->nationality = $nationality;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Mission>
     */
    public function getMissions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->missions;
    }

    public function addMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if (!$this->missions->contains($mission)) {
            $this->missions[] = $mission;
            $mission->addContact($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if ($this->missions->removeElement($mission)) {
            $mission->removeContact($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getCodeName();
    }
}
```

### Mission.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MissionRepository::class)]
class Mission
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column()]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $country = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Agent::class, inversedBy: 'missions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')]
    private Collection $agent;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Contact::class, inversedBy: 'missions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')]
    private Collection $contact;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Target::class, inversedBy: 'missions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')]
    private Collection $target;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Hideout::class, inversedBy: 'missions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')]
    private Collection $hideout;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $startDate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $endDate = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'missions')]
    private ?Speciality $speciality = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->agent = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->contact = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->target = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hideout = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Agent>
     */
    public function getAgent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->agent;
    }

    public function addAgent(Agent $agent): self
    {
        if (!$this->agent->contains($agent)) {
            $this->agent[] = $agent;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAgent(Agent $agent): self
    {
        $this->agent->removeElement($agent);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Contact>
     */
    public function getContact(): Collection
    {
        return $this->contact;
    }

    public function addContact(Contact $contact): self
    {
        if (!$this->contact->contains($contact)) {
            $this->contact[] = $contact;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeContact(Contact $contact): self
    {
        $this->contact->removeElement($contact);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Target>
     */
    public function getTarget(): Collection
    {
        return $this->target;
    }

    public function addTarget(Target $target): self
    {
        if (!$this->target->contains($target)) {
            $this->target[] = $target;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTarget(Target $target): self
    {
        $this->target->removeElement($target);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Hideout>
     */
    public function getHideout(): Collection
    {
        return $this->hideout;
    }

    public function addHideout(Hideout $hideout): self
    {
        if (!$this->hideout->contains($hideout)) {
            $this->hideout[] = $hideout;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHideout(Hideout $hideout): self
    {
        $this->hideout->removeElement($hideout);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(string $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function setStartDate(\DateTimeInterface $startDate): self
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEndDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    public function setEndDate(\DateTimeInterface $endDate): self
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSpeciality(): ?Speciality
    {
        return $this->speciality;
    }

    public function setSpeciality(?Speciality $speciality): self
    {
        $this->speciality = $speciality;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Use actions like the doc decribe [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html)  and so you can make validations, etc ... Also you can customize crud actions with [this doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#customizing-crud-actions). Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

EasyAdmin runs your entity's validation rules, so the easiest way to implement a validation rule is on the desired entity.

For this, I normally use the [Callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint.

This allows you to write a function in your entity that contains the exact validation logic you need. The only thing you'll need to decide is which field to attach the error to (field A or field B) in case they have filled out neither or both.

It changes slightly on different versions of Symfony, but i'll show an example on version 5.4 using annotations:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MissionRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="mission")
 */
class Mission {

    // ...
    
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload) {
        if ($this->getCountry() != $this->getContact()->getNationality()) {
            $context->buildViolation('The nationality of the contract must be the same as the country of the mission.')
                    ->atPath('contact')
                    ->addViolation();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

*Note: I'm using just one contact for readability, but you can use a foreach to check each contact*